# Jupyter in Pycharm - dataframe is not showing when dataframe is too wide, no horizontal scroll option appears

Tags: python, pycharm, scrollbar, jupyter-notebook

When I output a dataframe from a cell using jupyter notebook in Pycharm it won't display unless the width of the dataframe fits in the window. Hence, in cases where the width is wider than the window width, only a white line is produced, while I was expecting part of the dataframe as well as a horizontal scrollbar to show. Running the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

multiplier = 2
col = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase] * multiplier 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df.head()
```

produces:
[image]

But when the dataframe becomes too wide (multiplier=4), I get:

[image]

As mentioned before, I was hoping a horizontal scrollbar would show as it does conventionally. Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?

Comment: I also have this problem. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @JanJaniszewski,

No, I haven't I'm afraid. I think it will be up to Jetbrains to consider whether they want to address this in a future release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that JetBrains are aware of the issue and will hopefully address it soon.

You can track the development for updates via their PyCharm issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25931