# Jupyter notebook not displaying the tables in pycharm but showing in browser

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

It is my first time to use jupyter notebook and have tried to open it on pycharm.

I have the following functions in pycharm:
[image]

When I try to run the function It's not showing the tables that I'm trying to extract... instead it's just a long horizontal line:
[image]

Tried using jupyter notebook in the browser and it seems fine:

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing in using pyhcarm? not really sure maybe it's the darcula theme that I'm using? if so is there a way to change the font color of the table to properly display in my current theme setting?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661154/3368225 ? (the earlier post doesn't yet have an accepted or upvoted answer either)

Comment: A year later and I am still having this problem. Anyone fixed this?

Comment: Still having this problem also.. super annoying.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug currently in Pycharm especially if your columns exceed the display area. But in some cases you can increase the size of the display area by hiding the source files and tables will display

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the button of 'clear outputs' and try print again

Comment: This response would benefit from an explanation as to why you think this will fix the issue. Elsewise, it is probably commentary on the main post.